# what kind of algorithm should I use to classify the text data example given?

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, text-mining, text-classification

What kind of classification or learning algorithm that suits this kind of data example[image]

If I have to build a model  using the given key words then predict column B and then to column A?
what kind of algorithm should I use to train and classify the data of this format.

Comment: Can you assume that all the possible target values in column A and B are predefined? And do you have multiple examples for each value in column B? If the answer is no to any of these questions, it's not classification and it's going to be harder.

Comment: we can consider them to be one C = (A+B) and  using key words we can we classify.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, let me rephrase: if the data is split randomly between training and test set, would there be approximately the same labels in the training and test set, or most labels in the test set would be unique?

Comment: Yes I have multiple examples for each values in column B.

Comment: Ok so you can use classification then. One of the main question is the choice of text representation, it could be traditional TFIDF or embeddings, depending how large is the vocabulary, how many instances, etc.

Comment: can you paste the data as text (in addition to the screenshot) I have an idea that this is fairly easily handled by combination of tf/idf or topic modeling featurization followed by any of a few different basic algos

Answer (score 1):

When you wonder which algorithm works best for your data, you can try to use some packages like `pycaret` or `H2O` .

Documentation for `pycaret`: https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Documentation for `H2O`: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/intro.html

When I delt with a multiclass text classification in the past for me `support vector classifier` and `SGD Classifier` models worked well.
You can also try with an `LSTM`.