# How to generate labels for the text data given in excel files?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have a data given like this[image]

How do I convert this kind of data into a organized dataset like news group dataset https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html

Comment: Is this file a .csv? If so, what is its separator?

Comment: In what context you were asking separator?  actually they do not have any separators in .csv file if you were talking about (,.).

Comment: csv files are files in which data is stored sequentially and divided by a separator (common values are spaces, tabulations, commas or dots). Knowing the separator is the first step to read the file with pandas python library to create the dataset

Comment: So probably yours "they do not have any separators" means it is a space or a tabulation. Am I correct?

Comment: Its a space yes.

Comment: I'm confused: in your [previous question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/what-kind-of-algorithm-should-i-use-to-classify-the-text-data-example-given) you want to use column A and/or column B as label. I don't understand why you're asking to 'generate' some labels now: do you mean that you want to extract the labels that you have in the columns? If so it looks to me that DaSim was giving you the right answer.