# How do I Classify text data with multiple sub labels?

Tags: python, classification, multilabel-classification

If I have data that was like this
[image: data]

How can I train keywords and try to classify them into these labels what was the best algorithm to try this and labels are not limited to 4 might increase and some times sparse like in picture. any reference links with python mught be helpful.Thank You.

Comment: The question is not clear: is your data just a list of keywords or some text documents possibly containing these keywords? If text, what kind of text? Size, number of labels? Please give more detail.

Comment: We get keywords from semrush app we don’t have any text data that gives us the key word. The length of labels might vary form 5-10 like showed in the picture.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not clear to me: you have a fixed list of keywords and a label associated with them, right? If there's no text and the keywords are always the same, then there's no need for ML: you can just store the list of keywords in a map/dict with the label.

Comment: Keywords are not fixed those are the ones I need to train, I get updates with keywords every week now when I type in new keywords it should show me which label or category it belongs to.

Comment: Mmh this is likely to be very difficult without any context. I guess you would have to use a similarity measure between pretrained word embeddings. With the additional difficulty of hierarchical labels, I guess that you have a high number of labels right? You could do a system, but imho it's not going to work very well because you have very little input info and you're trying to predict a very diverse output.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/what-kind-of-algorithm-should-i-use-to-classify-the-text-data-example-given  can you look at this and say how to use any ML algorithm with combining columns as they did in the post.

Comment: The problem is not which ML algorithm to use, it's to specify and design the system correctly. So far you didn't even mention how many instances and labels there are, which are crucial info. Also the other question has every keyword multiple times in the data, do you have the same condition satisfied? Basically you need a serious analysis of the problem. FYI a experienced data scientist would certainly need at least to work a couple weeks full time on this kind of problem, it's not easy.

Comment: I have the same conditions met, I do have keywords and labels repeating multiple times. what do you suggest for that question I will try to execute the same.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114446/how-do-i-use-a-machine-learning-or-al-algorithm-on-this-kind-of-data  Look at this one I do have an almost similar kind of data.

Comment: As I said, what matters is the distribution of the labels and the size of the data. The linked question mentions that there is an input text for these labels, do you have an input text? You didn't answer my questions and you seem to hope that there's a magical ML algorithm that you can apply easily, it's not the case afaik. If you really want to apply a text classification algorithm and you don't care about the results, try Naive Bayes or decision tree.

Comment: Sorry, it is exactly the same as this link the goal is when I classify using keywords it has to print me subthematic and then thematic like in the link. but the problem I was seeing is how can I input labels to the training?do I need to use multiple models like model 1 between keyword and subthematic and model 2 between subthematic and thematic and keep track of results?https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114446/how-do-i-use-a-machine-learning-or-ai-algorithm-on-this-kind-of-data

Comment: There's no standard way to represent a hierarchy of labels. Try predicting the most detailed level of labels only: if it works well, it's easy to deduce the higher level; if it doesn't, then try the higher level.

Comment: So you were saying to train two models?

Comment: I mean you could try to train a model on the most specific labels, e.g. 'sport/referee/ball/two players'. If this doesn't work you go one level up, e.g. 'sport/referee/ball'. If it still doesn't work, use only two levels (e.g. 'sport/referee') as labels. But I don't think that will work, you task is not well specified.