# How do I use a machine learning or AI algorithm on this kind of data?

Tags: python, text-classification

I have a text data set with keyword, thematic, Sub thematic, intent Now I have to train a keyword then first classify into sub thematic, then into thematic and then into intent. the data looks like this [image]

What kind of machine learning algorithm should I need to do this? Does this comes under multi label classification? then there are no fixed labels

Comment: Please clarify: do you have a full input text for each line, or only the content of this table? In general this is not the regular case for multi-label classification, normally in multi-label the number of labels is not fixed. This could be a case of multiple models, simply.

Comment: I just have those words what ever you see this is the final thing that I need to train and classify. I don't have any text or context related to labels or keywords.

Comment: You need to use `@Erwan` otherwise I won't be notified of your reply. If you don't have any other text, then I don't think you need ML: just store the association "keyword -> thematic etc." in a dict/map and apply it. If you have only a single keyword as input feature, I don't see how text classification could help since there's no generalization involved.