# What input does SVM consider when doing the text classification?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I was using SVM for text classification

```
pipe_lr1 = Pipeline(steps=[('cv',TfidfVectorizer()),
                      ('lr_multi',MultiOutputClassifier(LinearSVC()))])
```

Will SVM takes data like sparse matrices like this?

```
(0, 320)    1.0
(1, 106)    0.7418635863640789
(1, 320)    0.6705508326943057
(2, 547)    0.5655985284555338
(2, 1062)   0.556131277628881
(2, 320)    0.6089468832762044
```

or when I convert these into vectors using todense()

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Which one of those will considered as inputs to svm In vector form or sparse form?

Comment: It is hard to see whole picture with one code line. Would you share you code included your text data/dataset loading portion?

Comment: I cannot upload data, this is all the code I have, after this I will use 
    `pipe_lr1.fit(x_train1,y_train1)` my question was what does SVM consider as Input data?

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. I didn't ask upload actual data. I want to see what kind text you want to analyze. Do you have any similar example of your data?

Comment: the data looks similar to this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/what-kind-of-algorithm-should-i-use-to-classify-the-text-data-example-given?noredirect=1#comment114925_113586